# Jenkins JobDSL access env var from credentialsBinding in steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to use the env var in steps, which i set with bindCredentials, so that i can then use this var further in a shell.

```
job('job') {
  triggers {
    cron('0 * * * *')
  }
  wrappers {
      credentialsBinding {
          usernamePassword(Config.GIT_TOKEN_ID, 'GIT_USER', 'GIT_TOKEN')
      }
  }
  steps {
      String resFile = sh(script: 'set +x; curl https://my-bitbucket.com/raw/src/collections/file.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_TOKEN"; set -x', returnStatus: true).trim()
  }
}
```

But there is the following error: `No such property: GIT_TOKEN for class:`

How do i access the credentials?

Comment: Use withCredentials to access the GIT_TOKEN environment variable inside script {}